# Empty choices in "Know someone who can answer?"

Tags: bug, status-declined, sharing

I am not sure if this is the right Stack Exchange site to post this, so please correct me if I am wrong.

I have recently noticed that the question "Know someone who can answer?" in a question page at the bottom is displayed that way in Stack Overflow:
"Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, , , or ."

This seems like a bug. Is Stack Exchange aware of this? I did not notice a duplicate question with a quick glance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is caused by AdBlock filters and is not related to Stack Exchange. [Read more.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214355/know-someone-who-can-answer-share-list-broken)