# Stack Overflow error: some links of "Know someone ~~~"

Tags: bug

**This is the error image:**
[image: error image]

It works properly on my iPad Safari, but errors on my browser

**What I've Tried**

1. Refresh
2. Hard refresh
3. Restart browser
4. Restart browser + refresh & hard refresh
5. Delete cookies
6. Disable Adblocks
7. Disable Brave Shield

**Environment**

- OS: macOS Big Sur 11.4
- Browser: Brave Browser 1.24.86 (don't care about brave shields, it both occurs when I turn on and off)

Comment: This is most likely caused by an ad-block extension or the like. Did you try running your browser in a clean session? FYI, the missing words/links are Facebook and Twitter share links.

Comment: Actually, this is a duplicate of: [Empty choices in "Know someone who can answer?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280798/empty-choices-in-know-someone-who-can-answer)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it doesn't helped me. Even when I disable all adblockers and tried on chrome, it does appear also.. :(

(I diabled all filters like brave shield, adguard, etc)

Comment: Well, in that case, I would wait for a staff member to investigate this. That said, I urge you to double-check that you disabled _all_ extensions? Edit: I initially thought you said you could also reproduce on Chrome. If you can't, please note that Brave browser is not amongst the [supported browsers](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) anyway, so I wouldn't put too much hope on this.

Comment: @41686d6564 I disabled ***ALL*** my extensions including brave shield but still the same.. :(